# One-liner PS scripts aren't working for me, About an old reddit post about talking-clock challenge

Tags: powershell, text-to-speech, clock

[Post Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/6jr76h/20170627_challenge_321_easy_talking_clock/?sort=confidence)

```
cat .\clockTimes.txt | %{"It's " + ($_ | get-date).ToShortTimeString() | Out-Speech}
```

```
(new-object -com SAPI.SpVoice).speak("It's "+($input | get-date).ToString("hh:mm tt"))
```

these two codes doesn't seem to be working.

**I want a clock to speak every 5 minutes.** like 09.05,09.10 like that, but not 09.01,09.06

Thanks in advance

i tried

```
PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak('hello');"
```

and change the content after .Speak(
but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(new-object -com SAPI.SpVoice).speak("It's "+($input = (get-date).ToString("hh:mm tt"))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**